# CSS selector of a parent node which has a certain descendant?

Tags: css

Suppose the structure is  `div > p`, can I apply styles to the div if p has a certain class name?

`div > p.b`    --> then apply red **to div**

`div > p.c`    --> another color

This is easy in jquery, but is it possible in pure CSS?

Comment: Short answer, no. Not in pure CSS.

Comment: But perhaps a different interesting answer is with a little help from a polyfill: https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector